# Re-orderable Listbox in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, slds

Does anyone know how to instantiate a re-orderable listbox in a Lightning page or component?

Here is the description of the Re-orderable Listbox:

https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/accessibility/patterns/listbox/

It looks like it might just be a `<ul>/<li>` construct, but I'm not sure what kind of slds tagging should be added.  Also, I'm assuming there are events fired when the user re-orders the elements.  I can't find any documentation on it.

Comment: There's a [dueling list box](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_dualListbox.htm), but I don't think there's a single list box in the wild today.

Comment: There are a number of them, but I have not found source samples.  Two examples from Lightning Experience are:  1) Setup > App Menu -- This presents a list of apps that can be dragged to re-order.  2) Setup > Object Manager > Contact > Lightning Record Pages > Contact Record Page > Edit -- Click on the right side panel (should be a tabs component).  The tabs can be reordered by dragging.